# Importance of Finding girth and all property testing like triangle-freeness

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

What is the application of finding girth of a graph? What is the use of property testing like if the graph is triangle-free or if the graph contains a cycle of length k? Couldn't get the applications easily on the wiki. Research papers proposing algorithms for solving these problems mention something about colour-coding. Could you please give elaborates references of their applications?

Comment: Mathematics doesn't need applications.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what do you suggest, where should I ask this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking it here.